# How to install Ubuntu server on a partition

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I have an empty partition and i want to install Ubuntu Server into it. However, when I have to choose the disks, it only lists guided and manual. If I use guided, then it uses up my whole hard drive. How do I install Ubuntu Server into a certain partition?

Comment: I'll be happy to help you along your way ... Using the manual option is better than using the guided option anyways ... Just need a few more details about what exactly you are trying to do. Do you have another operating system installed on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I do have another Ubuntu based system on the computer (Elementary Luna) and I already have a partition with 120 GB set up as ext3.

Comment: Cool cool, assuming Luna also uses grub as it's bootloader, it should be quite simple. It'll be quite long, so I'll add it as an answer, to help you use the Manual option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so select the `Manual` option

Then you will see a list of your partitions.

The easiest way to install it, would be to select the partition you want to install it to, select `Create Partition` -> Use the full size -> `Primary partition`

Then select the partition you have just created

Select `Use as` and choose `Ext4`

Then choose `Mount as` and select `\ - (root)` and select `Done setting up the partition`

Then select `Finish partitioning and write changes to disk`

This is a very simple setup (And not recommended, but will allow you to install it)

A better way would be to have seperate /boot partitions, swap areas and /home partitions. And also using lvm, but this is outside the scope of the question ...

If you want to know more about them, there is plenty on google :D